# Extracting lines consisting of three digits with Windows findStr

Tags: regex, findstr

when I am using the code in my windows CMD it is not giving me any output.

I am using `findstr -E ^[0-9]{3}$` and it does not provide the expected output.

This is a sample file:

```
834
519
4874
5
89
45687
25
645
```

Comment: Your code specified the start and end of a line. So the regex will try to match a line containing only 3 digits. Maybe remove the `^` and `$`

Comment: what do you want yo match by your regex share that

Comment: [`findstr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr) is not `grep`.

Comment: `findstr /R "^[0-9][0-9][0-9]$"`   (see: `findstr /?` for more info, and the link from  @WiktorStribiżew )

Answer (score 0):

Windows [*findStr*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr) is not *grep*, you need to use

```
findstr /r /c:"^[0-9][0-9][0-9]$" test.txt
```

The `/r` option makes `findStr` search for a "regex" pattern and `/c:"..."` uses the specified text as a literal search string.

Since the regex features findStr supports are [very limited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman/20159191#20159191), you can't use `{3}`, you need to repeat the `[0-9]` thrice. Test:

```
C:\>findstr /r /c:"^[0-9][0-9][0-9]$" test.txt
834
519
645
```

**Note**: to make it extract `645`, I had to make sure there is a trailing linebreak after this last line in the *test.txt* file.